# Is it possible to get image size by Image url using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, imageurl

There is an image url, this image's size must be reduced proportionally by the minimum width and height so that it can be shown in a template.

The aforementioned template and its content will be generated into the html using javascript.
So i have to find a way to get the image size from an image url using javascript so that the size of the image can be reduced proportionally, is it possible to do this?

I am working on asp.net and c#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: just check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/623174/782145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to load an image and scale it down proportionally to fit a certain space on your screen?

You don't need to calculate anything in that case but rather just set the CSS width/height to the maximum space you want to fit the image upon load.
The browser will itself scale the image proportionally down to fit the space

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but you can use a trick: The URL must be generated somewhere; probably on the server.

What you can do is generate this url: `http://domain/path/image.png?size=320x200`

The server will ignore the parameter `size` when the browser downloads the image but you can examine this part of the URL in your JavaScript.

Comment: i don't know how that with the inage from other websites.